# Need modified Euler's method equation to approximate exact solution of initial value problem.

Tags: numerical-methods

I am asked to solve the following problem.
*Use Euler's modified method to solve the initial value problem 
$\frac{dx}{dt} =\frac{1+x^2}{t} ,1\le t \le4, x(1)=0$*

The step size is not given here. 
Now, I can solve this using Euler's method but I am not able to find the formula for modified one in the mentioned textbook. So, I need the method here.
I need to use the following as textbook:
**Brain Bradie, A friendly Introduction to Numerical Analysis (Pearson)**

Comment: If we have an ODE $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(t,x)$ then IIRC the modified Euler's method says that $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{h}{2}\left[ f(t_n, x_n) + f(t_{n+1}, x_{n} + h f(t_n, x_n))\right]$ where $h = \Delta t$ is the step-size.

Comment: Can you post picture or source from where you got this method please.

Comment: It's from memory so I can't guarantee that this is the same method your book calls Euler's modified method. However if we do a simple [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=modified+eulers+methods&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=7jgrWMPDHdD38AevrbHYCA) then the three top hits all agree with this defintion.

Comment: Yes, now I got the method in textbook under the heading "The most common second-order Runge-Kutta methods"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the method under the name [Heuns's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun's_method), also as (explicit) trapezoidal method.

```
k1 = h*f( t  , x    )
k2 = h*f( t+h, x+k1 )

y += 0.5 * ( k1 + k2 )
```